# Instalação phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, instalador

Estou tentando instalar o phpmyadmin em um computador rodando o apache 1.3.27.
Fiz a instalação normalmente, mas quando tento acessar o link do phpmyadmin aparece o seguinte erro:

> The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
>   Apache/1.3.27 Server at localhost Port 80

Fiz a instalação normalmente alterando o config.inc.php como orienta em todo lugar. Estou usando Windows

*obs: Eu sei que o StackOverflow não é o lugar ideal pra isso, mas não acho nada na internet e como é uma ferramenta de desenvolvimento bem usada, talvez alguém tenha tido o mesmo problema.*

Comment: Porque não testa utilizar o `wamp`?

Comment: Eu não posso, só me pediram pra instalar o phpmyadmin, já tem sistemas antigos funcionando e eu não posso nem sequer mudar a versão do apache ou php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, só coloquei a pasta do phpMyAdmin dentro da WWW do EasyPHP e funcionou.

Answer (score 3):

/* UPDATE */

Vai na config do Apache (httpd.conf) e abaixo de **Alias /home/mysql "${path}/phpmyadmin** add essa linha:

```
Alias /mysql "${path}/phpmyadmin"
```

/* ANTIGO */

Tenta esses comandos:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

No final do arquivo adicionar:

```
/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Depois reinicie o apache com:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

É linux ou windows?

Comment: É um computador com Windows

Comment: Funcionou? Senão tenho outra opção para tentar.

Comment: Não funcionou. :(

Comment: Espera, esses comandos são pra ser executados no CMD? é que diz que sudo não é um comando.

Comment: Qual o programa que está usando para executar o Apache? Por exemplo, existe o wamp e o xampp.

Comment: usando o easyPHP

Comment: Postei uma nova forma, senão funcionar, se der, desinstala e instala novamente.

Comment: Então, aqui não está bem desse jeito, mas tem algo assim: Alias /mysql/ `"C:/Program Files/EasyPHP1-7/phpmyadmin/"

    <Directory "C:/Program Files/EasyPHP1-7/phpmyadmin">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        allow from 127.0.0.1
        deny from all
    </Directory>`

Comment: Tente mudar essas opções para:                                          
"AllowOverride all"
 "Order Allow,Deny"
 "Allow from all" "Allow from 127.0.0.1" Salva e reinicia o apache.